# How to use TTLinearGradientBorderStyle

Tags: iphone, three20

Good day Mates,

I'm using Three20 in an iPhone Project, and I want to style my Table Items with a gradient background from the bottom. I was just wondering if this TTLinearGradientBorderStyle can help, but I can't find any sources how to use it. or if anyone has another idea how to do it, it would be great

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think another alternative for doing a gradient table item would be this [tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2009/10/how-to-make-ultra-slick-gradient-uitableview-cells/), it may not use three20 but this is mostly what I need~